# ObjC unusual behavior when casting NSUInteger to double

Tags: objective-c, casting, double, negative-number, nsuinteger

I'm experiencing some strange behavior when I negate a NSUInteger and cast to a double.

```
NSUInteger test = 10;
NSLog(@"%d", test);
NSLog(@"%f", (double) test);
NSLog(@"%d", -test);
NSLog(@"%f", (double) -test);
```

The output is:

```
10
10.000000
-10
4294967286.000000
```

Any ideas why this is the case?  I'm using NSUInteger because that's what's returned from [NSArray count].  I can easily use an int instead with no problems, and I will, but I'm extremely curious as to why this is the behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `NSUInteger` is an unsigned integer type. So it is when it's negated (`- test` is **still** an unsigned integer). But since an unsigned integer cannot hold negative values, it overflows and wraps around modulo 2 to the `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(NSUInteger)`th power. `NSUInteger` is 32 bit long on your platform, so you will get `-10 mod 4294967296` which is exactly 4294967286.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I thought it would be something like that, although I'm surprised that the third line worked in that case.  Do you know why NSLog("%d", -test) printed out "-10"?

Comment: @LukeGodfrey Because that interpreted the unsigned integer as a signed one, and you got **signed** integer overflow (basically the same thing, the other way around, but additionally it's UB as well).